# Highlight differences in rows by matching colum value from two worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I retrieve data from a database to an excel file. If I make a change in the database, and retrive a new "dump" in an excel file, I would like to know what changes have been made since the last time data was retrieved. I'm rather new to coding and have met my limitations with this problem. What I neeed to do is compare a name/ID with a matching name in colum 1 for ws1 vs colum 1 for ws2 and highlight the differences in ws2 for the values in each row. However, the name might be in a different row between each dump as new names get added/deleted.

I've tried some code that simply compares values in each cell, which is great if the names/ID's are in the same row position vs the worksheet i'm comparing against. However, if the name is in a different row, the whole dataset under that row will be considered a change and highlighted.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Call compareSheets("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

End Sub

Sub compareSheets(shtSheet1 As String, shtSheet2 As String)

Dim mycell As Range
Dim mydiffs As Integer

    'For each cell in sheet2 that is not the same in Sheet1, color it yellow
For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet2).UsedRange
    If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then

        mycell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        mydiffs = mydiffs + 1


    End If

    'If the cell has a matching value change it to "no fill"
    If mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then
        mycell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
Next

    'msg to display no. of difference found
MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found", vbInformation

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shtSheet2).Select

End Sub
```

```
WORKSHEET 1
Tag         Temperature    Pressure
13L0001A1   40             20
13L0002A2   40             25
13L0003A3   35             25

WORKSHEET 2
Tag         Temperature    Pressure
13L0001A1   40             20
13L0002A2   45             20
13L0003A3   35             25
```

This is an example of a dataset I would like to comapre. (very simplified, my actual dataset contains 45 colums). I need to highlight the change in temperature and pressure for tag 13L0002A2.

Any help would be highly apprciated!

**EDIT:**
Here is the new code I'm trying to implement:

```
Public Sub comparesheets(shtSheet1 As String, shtSheet2 As String)

    Dim rowCount1 As Integer
    Dim rowCount2 As Integer

        rowCount1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        rowCount2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("D2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D2:D" & rowCount1)
    Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("D2:D" & rowCount2)

    Dim var As Variant, iSheet As Integer

    'Cycle through all the cells in that column:
    For rowCount1 = 4 To rng1
    Next rowCount1

    'For every cell that is not empty, search through the column "D" in each worksheet for the
    'value that matches that cell value in the workbook.
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(rowCount1, 4)) Then
        For iSheet = ActiveSheet.Index + 4 To Worksheets.Count
        var = Application.Match(Cells(rng1, 4).Value, Worksheets(iSheet).Columns(4), 0)
        Next iSheet
    End If


    'If a matching value is found, then search each row for differences. If difference is found, color the cell yellow.
    'otherwise, continue searching until you reach the end of the workbook.
    If Not IsError(var) Then

        For Each rng1 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).UsedRange

                If Not rng2.Value = rng1.Value Then
                rng2.Interior.Color = vbYellow

                If Not rng2.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
                rng2.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow

                End If
        ' Here i get an error with "Next without For"
        Next rng1

    End If


    ' If no match is found, color entire row yellow
    If IsError(var) Then
    EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow

    End If

End Sub
```

If I add a Next statement after the For Each cell i get an error that says Next without For. If i don't add a Next statement i get an error that says Block If without End If.

Any suugestions to what might be wrong?

**2nd EDIT:**

So I tried to modify the example code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match beacause this is pretty much doing what I need. I successfully got the code to work, once. I then cleared all the formats to try again, and ran into an subscript out of range error ("9) and I cant for the life of me figure out why it worked once, and not now.

The code I used:

```
Sub HighlightMatches()

    'Declare variables
    Dim var As Variant, iSheet As Integer, iRow As Long, iRowL As Long, bln As Boolean, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rowCount1 As Integer, rowCount2 As Integer

        rowCount1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        rowCount2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("D4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

        Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D4:D" & rowCount1)
        Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("D4:D" & rowCount2)

       'Set up the count as the number of filled rows in the first column of Sheet1.
        iRowL = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

       'Cycle through all the cells in that column:
       For iRow = 4 To iRowL

          'For every cell that is not empty, search through the column "D" in each worksheet in the
          'workbook for a value that matches that cell value.
          If Not IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 4)) Then
             For iSheet = ActiveSheet.Index + 1 To Worksheets.Count
                bln = False
                var = Application.Match(Cells(iRow, 4).Value, Worksheets(iSheet).Columns(4), 0)

                'If you find a matching value, indicate success by setting bln to true and exit the loop;
                'otherwise, continue searching until you reach the end of the workbook.
                If Not IsError(var) Then
                   bln = True
                   Exit For
                End If
             Next iSheet
          End If

          'If match is found, compare row for each colum;
          'if no match is found, color cell yellow.
          If Not bln = True Then
           For Each rng1 In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
                If Not rng1.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(rng2.Row, 4) Then
                    rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = vbYellow
                End If
           Next rng1
          End If
       Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: For each row in sheet1, use `Application.Match` to locate the matching row in sheet2, then loop over both rows and compare.

Comment: Hi, I tried to do an application match, however im not sure i got it quite right. Do you see any obvious mistakes in my code? See my edited post for referance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to TIm, here is the solution for my problem:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Call comparesheets("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

End Sub

Public Sub comparesheets(shtSheet1 As String, shtSheet2 As String)

   Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, c As Range, cTest As Range, cMatch As Range, m
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

    For Each c In ws1.Range(ws1.Range("D2"), ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Cells
        m = Application.Match(c.Value, ws2.Columns(4), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            'match row, compare values
            For Each cTest In Application.Intersect(c.EntireRow, ws1.UsedRange).Cells
                Set cMatch = ws2.Cells(m, cTest.Column)
                If cTest.Value <> cMatch.Value Then
                    cMatch.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                End If
            Next cTest
        Else
            'no match found
            c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
            Debug.Print "No match for '" & c.Value & "' (Row " & c.Row & ")"
        End If
    Next c

'do a loop for worksheet 2
    For Each c In ws2.Range(ws2.Range("D2"), ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Cells
        m = Application.Match(c.Value, ws1.Columns(4), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            'match row, compare values
            For Each cTest In Application.Intersect(c.EntireRow, ws2.UsedRange).Cells
                Set cMatch = ws1.Cells(m, cTest.Column)
                If cTest.Value <> cMatch.Value Then
                    cMatch.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                End If
            Next cTest
        Else
            'no match
            c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
            Debug.Print "No match for '" & c.Value & "' (Row " & c.Row & ")"
        End If
    Next c

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'reset format button
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.ClearFormats
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells.ClearFormats

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Public Sub comparesheets(shtSheet1 As String, shtSheet2 As String)

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, c As Range, cTest As Range, cMatch As Range, m
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

    For Each c In ws1.Range(ws1.Range("D2"), ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Cells
        m = Application.Match(c.Value, ws2.Columns(4), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            'matched rows - compare values
            For Each cTest In Application.Intersect(c.EntireRow, ws1.UsedRange).Cells
                Set cMatch = ws2.Cells(m, cTest.Column)  '<<< EDIT
                If cTest.Value <> cMatch.Value Then
                    cMatch.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End If
            Next cTest
        Else
            'no matched row
            c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Debug.Print "No match for '" & c.Value & "' (Row " & c.Row & ")"
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot! However this seems to have the same problem my first attempt had. Once i add a new row number with a new Tag all the rows under that new Tag is conisdered a "change" it seems and gets highlighted.

Comment: Sorry about that -see my edit above.  That should fix it.

Comment: Awsome! One small thing, the new row does not get highlighted in sheet2, the diffrences in matched rows for sheet2 does.New rows does get highlighted in sheet1 if I add a new row there (which is good, I will then be able to tell if a row has been deleted in sheet2). Is this beacause "c" is only defined for ws1? I tried to work around this but couldn't quite get there. Other than that this seems to work perfect!

Comment: It wasn't clear that there could be new rows in either sheet which will not be present in the other one - my code only checks for new rows in sheet1.  If there could be rows only found in sheet2 then you'll need another loop to check for that, running a match against sheet1.

Comment: I've forgotten to thank you Tim, code works flawlessly :)